# Using a list to access database from a layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, loop, list

I am trying to access the database using a list in order to put it in a loop but I can't make it work. I want to replace the months with a list variable.

This is the hard core example:

```
   arcpy.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer_ga(in_ga_model_source="Areal 
Interpolation",in_datasets="London X=London.Shape Y=London.Shape 
F1=London.february",out_layer="february_interpolation")
```

I have list with the months which is:

```
    myMonths =['january', 'february',  'march','april','may','june','july', 
'august', 'september', 'october',   'november', 'december']
```

I am trying to find a way to change the months within a loop. I tried the following but I am sure that it doesn't work.

```
    arcpy.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer_ga(in_ga_model_source="Areal 
Interpolation",in_datasets="London X=London.Shape Y=London.Shape F1=London.%d"
 %myMonths[1],out_layer=myMonths[1]+"_interpolation")
```

I tried to find the answer but I was unable to find suitable search terms.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it for Month in myMonths: arcpy.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer_ga(i...F1=London."+Month...out_layer=Month + "_interpolation") or something like that?

Comment: Yes that it what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% formatting works but only within a string:

```
myString = "%d_rest" % (Number)
```

will substitute a number into the string.. for inserting a string use %s:

```
myString = "%s_rest" % (InsertString)
```

For your case a simple append might be the best:

```
myMonths =['january', 'february',  'march','april','may','june','july','august', 'september', 'october',   'november', 'december']
for Month in myMonths:
    # break this down for readability
    src    = "Areal Interpolation"
    inDS   = "London X=London.Shape Y=London.Shape F1=London." + Month
    outLay =  Month + "_interpolation"
    arcpy.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer_ga(in_ga_model_source=src,in_datasets=inDS,out_layer=outLay)
```

Improved formatting can be gained with the string.format() function:

```
myString = "{0}_rest".format(Number)
myString = "{0}_rest".format(InsertString)
```

Both work the same for numbers and strings which makes them preferable, but still you can't substitute over a list of arguments - one string only!